# sending html form to an email

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to send an email containing a form that is meant to be filled and submitted? The recipient is required to fill the form right from the email and submit it.

Comment: Yes it is possible, have you found/tried anything?

Comment: You can send HTML emails.  HTML can contain a form.  Did you try?

Comment: I have tried but I get difficult in receiving the feedback filled on that form. Or rather the form does not submit any information

Comment: Html in e-mail is pretty limited and design like this are probably blocked by most e-mail providers due to security.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is, unfortunately, **No**. While HTML email (as opposed to plain text email) can, in theory, include any HTML code, most email clients (I'd say "all" but I'm not certain) do not support `<form>` tags. They may show the form, but the form won't function as expected, at least not in any consistent way. I have found in both emails I have received from numerous organizations large & small, and in my own programming, that the typical solution is to have the body of the email (text, graphics or buttons) link to a web page containing the form. That allows the form to support all standard HTML, Javascript (which most (again, probably "all" but I'm not sure) email clients don't support, loading of linked files (which many email programs turn off by default and ask the user before displaying to avoid security issues), CSS (which most email programs support in general as inline CSS but generally not with support for loading external CSS files), etc. and to function in a secure (https protocol) environment.

If the form needs to start off with email-recipient-specific information (e.g., showing the user's name, email address filled in, etc.) then the link from the email should include a parameter that either includes the raw data (if security/spoofing is not an issue) or references a database record that contains the recipient's data. If security is important (i.e., you don't want the recipient to be able to mess around with the generated URL/parameters and possibly see another user's name or impersonate someone else) then you can encode that information and include a checksum or hash of some sort so that randomly tweaking the parameters will result in your web form displaying "Sorry, the parameters are incorrect. Contact us or click here for a blank form..." etc.

Comment: Not true; I've done it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What email programs were you able to get to work with it? Thunderbird? Eudora? iOS standard email? Android standard email?

Comment: I've coded this in PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP generates your HTML. My question is: Once you have generated an HTML email and sent it, if the recipient is using Outlook (on a local computer, not webmail) can they complete the form inside their email program and submit it successfully?

Comment: Although I've never tested it with a client side mailer, I assume it would be the same and using a URL for the form's action. Theoretically, this should work the same as a form being filled on Gmail for example, which is what I tested with some time ago.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is one of those situations where "assume it would be the same" fails miserably. Gmail (and most other webmail programs, but not all) support full HTML by default since they are functioning in a browser already - i.e., they don't have to do any extra work to support forms, external CSS, etc. and the security issues are a little different (some ways better, some ways worse) because the browser is a different environment than a native application. If you can make it work with Outlook (native client-side), Thunderbird, iOS mail and Android mail, I'd love to see the code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That being said, if you have a very closed environment - e.g., a corporate or school organization where everyone must use Gmail and most (by default) use the Gmail web page instead of a separate client application, that would be fine. But that isn't the typical real-world usage in my experience.

Comment: that would be beyond our control. All I can say in my defense is that, it can be done since I have done it. Their question was too broad to begin with. For what it's actually used / intended for, is unknown. It showed no specifics nor any effort.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree the question was too broad. I interpreted it as "Is it possible to send an *HTML* email *to a broad range of users on unknown but typical email systems* containing a form that is meant to be filled and submitted? The recipient is required to fill the form right from the email *within the client email program or webmail system* and submit it *without using a web browser (unless their email system runs in a web browser)*."